# Customizing spring security requestmap in grails 2.3.5

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am using Grails : 2.3.5
and Spring Security Core plugin : 1.2.7.3

In Grails Spring Security [RequestMap](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/domainClasses.html#requestmapClass) is a separate table but in my application I want to use the requestMap concept with the existing table.

I have a RolePermissionMap table is there and I want to use this table for the RequestMap.

```
class Role{
    Long id
    String name
    String description
}

class Permission{
    Long id
    String name
    String description
    String requestUrl
}

class RolePermissionMap {
    Long id
    Role role
    Permission permission
}
```

Now I am overriding the loadRequestmaps() method by extending the [RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/web/access/intercept/RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.java) class like below

```
class RolePermissionMapFilterInvocation extends RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> loadRequestmaps() {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (Object requestmap : ReflectionUtils.loadAllRequestmaps()) {

            // Original code
            //String urlPattern = ReflectionUtils.getRequestmapUrl(requestmap);
            //String configAttribute = ReflectionUtils.getRequestmapConfigAttribute(requestmap);
            //data.put(urlPattern, configAttribute); 

            // modified code
            Permission permission = ReflectionUtils.getRequestmapUrl(requestmap);
            Role role = ReflectionUtils.getRequestmapConfigAttribute(requestmap);
            data.put(permission.getRequestUrl(), role.getName());
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Then I will add this bean in resources.groovy

```
beans = {
     objectDefinitionSource(RolePermissionMapFilterInvocation)
}
```

I am also trying to override the ReflectionUtils class also for getting the return types of getRequestmapUrl(requestmap) and getRequestmapConfigAttribute() methods also as required

When I run with this approach am getting exception below

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectDefinitionSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: url matcher is required

for resolving the url matcher I added a bean in resources.groovy but it failed

Do I need to create a bean with urlMaper or need to mention ReflectionUtils class any where ?

Please show me a way.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The plugin expects the `url` field in your request map class to be a String, in order to use a different type you'd have to subclass [RequestMapFilterInvocationDefinition](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/web/access/intercept/RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.java) to extract the URL patterns correctly, and install your custom class as the bean named `objectDefinitionSource` in your app's resources.groovy to replace the default bean definition supplied by [SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy) in its `doWithSpring`.

Comment: This works fine when am using grails "spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"    plugin. But I need to use grails "spring-security-core:1.2.7.3" plugin, In this when I am trying to implement the RequestMapFilterInvocationDefinition but there are no classes(InterceptedUrl and ReflectionUtils) to implement this and also I am unable to find the document of plugin to implement. 
Please help me if you have any idea on this..
Thanks in advance

Comment: @varun RequestMapFilterInvocationDefinition is still there in version 1.x, just [in a different package](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/1.x/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.java), and there isn't an InterceptedUrl class as the method you'd need to override simply returns a Map.

Comment: While am developing with the 1.x version I am getting "url matcher is required" which is located in AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition    class. What I understood is in 1.x version just _urlMatcher variable is declared but in later version it is defined as AntPathMatcher urlMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();  I tried with dependency Injection to urlMatcher but it's not working. Please suggest me for implementation. Thanks in advance